# Return RedirectToAction does not return new View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a method which return an action to a different controller. I am using `return RedirectToAction` and passing a parameter with it. The parameter successfully passed to the other controller. But it does not return any view. The page should load and return a new view. Here is my code:

Controller 1:

```
public ActionResult Work(int id, int staffId)
{            
    return RedirectToAction("CreateStaffWork", "Staff", new { id = staffId});
}
```

Controller 2 (Staff):

```
public ActionResult CreateStaffWork(int id)
{
    Staff staffInfo= db.Staff.Find(id);
    StaffInputModel newStaffWork = new StaffInputModel { StaffId = staffInfo.Id };
    return View(newStaffWork);
}
```

It should return `CreateStaffWork` view, but the page does not reload. There is no error while running the code. What should I do for the view to return?

I submit the form using ajax request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#LoadStaffListTable tbody").on('click', '.select', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/StaffWork/Work',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { id: $(this).data('id'), staffId: $(this).data('staffId') },
                dataType: 'json',
            }); // end ajax
        });
});
```

Comment: The code you have shown will work fine, so best guess is your actually making an ajax call.

Comment: Is the redirect happening ? Are you seeing `/CreateStaffWork?id=someId` as the url in your browser ? Your code looks fine.

Comment: The process went to `return View(newStaffWork);`, but page does not reload at all. no change in the url

Comment: @StephenMuecke i dont use any ajax in the view

Comment: What happens when you enter `../Staff/CreateStaffWork/1` in the browser address bar

Comment: When I enter `../Staff/CreateStaffWork/1`, The page not found. But when I enter `../Staff/CreateStaffWork?id=1` it shows the correct page

Comment: Then your have changed the route definitions so you not using the default route, however that that still does not explain the issue fully (the code you have shown does work). Show the relevant part to the view that is redirecting to your `Work()` method

Comment: I try to redirect to a controller which return a view without passing any parameter. `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`. but it does not reload the Index page.

Comment: Again - **Show the relevant part to the view that is redirecting to your `Work()` method**

Comment: *updated. i do use ajax in order to submit the form to `Work()`. But no ajax request used in `CreateStaffWork` view.

Comment: You previously stated your not using ajax, but your edit clearly shows you are. The whole point of ajax is to stay in the **same** page! Ajax calls **never** redirect. If you want to redirect, do not use ajax. (in any case, your specifying `dataType: 'json',` so you would be throwing an exception anyway since your returning html)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the purpose of ajax is to stay in the same page. If you're redirecting to a new page, you simply redirect to the `Work` action methods with proper parameters.

Change your `click` event handler to:

```
$("#LoadStaffListTable tbody").on('click', '.select', function(e) {
  location.href = '@Url.Action("Work", "StaffWork")?id=' + $(this).data('id') + '&staffId=' + $(this).data('staffId');
});
```